# eclipse/netbeans: categorize/collapsing code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ide

is there someway you can categorize the code your are writing in these two programs.

eg. if you have a function you can click the - sign on the left and it will collapse the function. but if i want to collapse a section of codes with some functions and procedural code, how can i do that?

then you can have different "chapters" like in Word. And you can see the whole pictures of just having the "headers" in front of you.

eg. in your js-file.

--- All views ---

--- Main view ---

--- Thread view ---

and so on...

Any other suggestions for improving visibility of you code structure is also welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several years ago there was an Eclipse plugin which can do that, the [Coffee Bytes](http://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/) plugin (blog [here](http://themindstorms.blogspot.com/2006/09/eclipse-api-and-code-folding.html)). It allows you to add user-definied start and end points of folding. Unfortunately, the project is currently dead and not anymore maintained, but you can still download the latest version of the plugin [here](http://coffee-bytes.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fixes_04_09_27/distro/com.cb.eclipse.folding1.0.6.200611020605S%20.zip). No wording about Netbeans here as I don't use it.

I myself however don't make use of it. I just mark groups with a comment line which is tailed with hyphens `-` all the way up to the max line length, they are easy enough to spot.

E.g.

```
// Init -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function init() {
    // ...
}
```

You can also consider to put the title at the end of the line so that it's easier to spot on while searching, although it may be less intuitive for beginners:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- Init

function init() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but its so troublesome to count the hyphens all the time. cause i have to have different headers like h3 h2 h1 and so on...it would be better if they were somehow autogenerated with the program.

Comment: Count? I just make use of the "show print margin" feature of my IDE which is set to 100 chars wide.

Comment: but the problem is still that you can not collapse all the headers like with the functions...

Comment: r u = are you
they are sms short form

Comment: @test: yes, I discovered that `r` and `u` are used by low intellects. See also http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=u